# Image Carousel using Twitter Bootstrap and Orchard CMS

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms

I am using Orchard CMS and the Bootstrap theme. I have been trying to use the carousel built in bootstrap to work as shown in the following blog post: http://www.stevetaylor.me.uk/image-carousel-using-twitter-bootstrap-and-orchard-cms-projections. I have followed the tutorial but i cannot get my new layout file to appear in the query under grid and html list. I believe i have copied the code word for word but still can get it to work. Anybody please help with this as  think it would be a great feature to add. if i get it to work i will request it gets added to the bootstrap theme here: http://orchardbootstrap.codeplex.com/

See code below:

**CarouselLayoutForm.cs**

```
using System;
using Orchard.DisplayManagement;
using Orchard.Forms.Services;
using Orchard.Localization;

namespace Orchard.Projections.Providers.Layouts {

public class CarouselLayoutForms : IFormProvider {
    protected dynamic Shape { get; set; }
    public Localizer T { get; set; }

    public CarouselLayoutForms(
        IShapeFactory shapeFactory) {
        Shape = shapeFactory;
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
    }

    public void Describe(DescribeContext context) {
        Func<IShapeFactory, object> form =
            shape => {

                var f = Shape.Form(
                    Id: "CarouselLayout",                        
                    _HtmlProperties: Shape.Fieldset(
                        Title: T("Html properties"), 
                        _ListId: Shape.TextBox(
                            Id: "outer-grid-id", Name: "OuterDivId",
                            Title: T("Outer div id"),
                            Description: T("The id to provide on the div element."),
                            Classes: new[] { "textMedium", "tokenized" }
                            ),
                        _ListClass: Shape.TextBox(
                            Id: "outer-div-class", Name: "OuterDivClass",
                            Title: T("Outer div class"),
                            Description: T("The class to provide on the div element."),
                            Classes: new[] { "textMedium", "tokenized" }
                            ),
                        _InnerClass: Shape.TextBox(
                            Id: "inner-div-class", Name: "InnerDivClass",
                            Title: T("Inner div class"),
                            Description: T("The class to provide on the inner div element."),
                            Classes: new[] { "textMedium", "tokenized" }
                            ),
                         _FirstItemClass: Shape.TextBox(
                            Id: "first-item-class", Name: "FirstItemClass",
                            Title: T("First item class"),
                            Description: T("The class to provide on the first item element."),
                            Classes: new[] { "textMedium", "tokenized" }
                            ),
                        _ItemClass: Shape.TextBox(
                            Id: "item-class", Name: "ItemClass",
                            Title: T("Item class"),
                            Description: T("The class to provide on the item element."),
                            Classes: new[] { "textMedium", "tokenized" }
                            )
                        )
                    );

                return f;
            };

        context.Form("CarouselLayout", form);

    }
}
   /*
public class CarouselLayoutFormsValitator : FormHandler {
    public Localizer T { get; set; }

    public override void Validating(ValidatingContext context) {
        if (context.FormName == "CarouselLayout") {
            if (context.ValueProvider.GetValue("Alignment") == null) {
                context.ModelState.AddModelError("Alignment", T("The field Alignment is required.").Text);
            }

            if (context.ValueProvider.GetValue("Columns") == null) {
                context.ModelState.AddModelError("Columns", T("The field Columns/Lines is required.").Text);
            }
            else {
                int value;
                if (!Int32.TryParse(context.ValueProvider.GetValue("Columns").AttemptedValue, out value)) {
                    context.ModelState.AddModelError("Columns", T("The field Columns/Lines must be a valid number.").Text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
*/

}
```

**CarouselLayout.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Orchard.ContentManagement;
using Orchard.DisplayManagement;
using Orchard.Localization;
using Orchard.Projections.Descriptors.Layout;
using Orchard.Projections.Models;
using Orchard.Projections.Services;

namespace Orchard.Projections.Providers.Layouts {
public class CarouselLayout : ILayoutProvider {
    private readonly IContentManager _contentManager;
    protected dynamic Shape { get; set; }

    public CarouselLayout(IShapeFactory shapeFactory, IContentManager contentManager) {
        _contentManager = contentManager;
        Shape = shapeFactory;
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
    }

    public Localizer T { get; set; }

    public void Describe(DescribeLayoutContext describe) {
        describe.For("Html", T("Html"),T("Html Layouts"))
            .Element("Carousel", T("Carousel"), T("Organizes content items in a carousel."),
                DisplayLayout,
                RenderLayout,
                "CarouselLayout"
            );
    }

    public dynamic RenderLayout(LayoutContext context, IEnumerable<LayoutComponentResult> layoutComponentResults) {

        string outerDivClass = context.state.outerDivClass;
        string OuterDivId = context.state.OuterDivID;
        string innerDivClass = context.state.InnerDicClass;
        string firstItemClass = context.state.FirstItemClass;
        string itemClass = context.state.ItemClass;

        IEnumerable<dynamic> shapes =
           context.LayoutRecord.Display == (int)LayoutRecord.Displays.Content
               ? layoutComponentResults.Select(x => _contentManager.BuildDisplay(x.ContentItem, context.LayoutRecord.DisplayType))
               : layoutComponentResults.Select(x => x.Properties);

        return Shape.Carousel(Id: outerDivId, Items: shapes, OuterClasses: new[] { outerDivClass }, 
                InnerClasses: new[] {innerDivClass}, FirstItemClasses: new[] {firstItemClass}, ItemClasses: new[] {itemClass});
    }
}
}
```

**LayoutShapes.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using Orchard.ContentManagement;
using Orchard.DisplayManagement;
using Orchard.Localization;
using Orchard.Mvc.Html;
using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;

namespace Orchard.Projections.Providers.Layouts {
public class LayoutShapes : IDependency {
    public LayoutShapes() {
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
    }

    public Localizer T { get; set; }

    [Shape]
    public void Carousel(dynamic Display, TextWriter Output, HtmlHelper Html, string Id, IEnumerable<dynamic> Items, 
                        IEnumerable<string> OuterClasses, IDictionary<string, string> OuterAttributes,
                        IEnumerable<string> InnerClasses, IDictionary<string, string> InnerAttributes, 
                        IEnumerable<string> FirstItemClasses, IDictionary<string, string> FirstItemAttributes, IEnumerable<string> ItemClasses,  IDictionary<string, string> ItemAttributes ) 
    {            
        if (Items == null) return;

        var items = Items.ToList();
        var itemsCount = items.Count;

        if (itemsCount < 1) return;

        var outerDivTag = GetTagBuilder("div", Id, OuterClasses, OuterAttributes);
        var innerDivTag = GetTagBuilder("div", string.Empty, InnerClasses, InnerAttributes);
        var firstItemTag = GetTagBuilder("div", string.Empty, FirstItemClasses, FirstItemAttributes);
        var itemTag = GetTagBuilder("div", string.Empty, ItemClasses, ItemAttributes);

        Output.Write(outerDivTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
        Output.Write(innerDivTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));

        int i = 0;

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (i== 0)
               Output.Write(firstItemTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag)); 
            else
               Output.Write(itemTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag)); 

            Output.Write(Display(item));
            Output.Write(itemTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));
            i++;
        }

        Output.Write(innerDivTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));

        Output.Write("<a href=\"#{0}\" class=\"carousel-control left\" data-slide=\"prev\">&lsaquo;</a>",id);
        Output.Write("<a href=\"#{0}\" class=\"carousel-control right\" data-slide=\"next\">&lsaquo;</a>",id);

        Output.Write(outerDivTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));

        Output.Write("<script>$(function () {$('"+ Id +"').carousel();}); </script>");

    }

    static TagBuilder GetTagBuilder(string tagName, string id, IEnumerable<string> classes, IDictionary<string, string> attributes) {
        var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder(tagName);
        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(attributes, false);
        foreach (var cssClass in classes ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>())
            tagBuilder.AddCssClass(cssClass);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
            tagBuilder.GenerateId(id);
        return tagBuilder;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Did you enable the feature? Do you see any exceptions in app_data\logs?

Comment: i am using orchard 1.6 and the projector module is already enabled. The log files are empty in the folder you specified. Thanks for your help.

Comment: bertrand le roy i have added compile references and module reference to forms and projections in the theme by editing the .csproj file. Now i get errors in the log file: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Orchard.Themes.Models.ThemeEntry' to 'Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentPart'. Please advise if possible

Comment: I wasn't talking about the projection module, but about your module, the one where you defined this layout.

Comment: For the implicit conversion thing, that's more a C# question. Try to explicitly cast.

Comment: Thanks for your help and comments. I have maanged to get it working. Although i looks terrible so i need to look at that next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add your code to the module Orchard.Projections as explained?
You need to add the files in Visual Studio and to save the project for them to be included in the .csproj (unless, the dynamic compilation won't take the files in account), or you can build the module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just created the folder and sub folder and dropped the new files init from the post using webmatrix. I have not compiled anything as I though the theme was compiled on the fly, I don't see a bin folder etc. please advise what should I do.

Comment: If you don't have Visual Studio, you must add these kind of lines to the .csproj for all the files : 

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Provider\Layout\LayoutShapes.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: Thanks again for replying. I have added those files as suggested: <ItemGroup>
    <Compile  Include="Providers\Layouts\CarouselLayout.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
    <Compile  Include="Providers\Layouts\CarouselLayoutForms.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
    <Compile  Include="Providers\Layouts\LayoutShapes.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

but this still does not. I do not understand though why this even needs a .csproj as other themes do not have them ie TheThemeMachine.

Comment: i have also added this <itemGroup><ProjectReference Include="..\..\Modules\Orchard.Projections\Orchard.Projections.csproj">
      <Project>{5531E894-D259-45A3-AA61-26DBE720C1CE}</Project>
      <Name>Orchard.Projections</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>

but still i cant get it to appear. I really cant understand why this wont work. Antoine i downloaded the contoso theme and you are right they use a project file and have a section with compile filepath to file. 

Plese help

Comment: You'd better need Visual Studio to do that kind of development or else, you won't see compile issuess, ...
It is also easier to include files or add references, as they say in the comments of the article : 
Once you copied the files over you'll need to add the references that are required for that file inside you theme project. Try adding a reference to Orchard.Projections and Orchard.Forms.

Comment: Thanks Antoine i will give it a go with visual studio instead and report back. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks Antoine for all your help. I opened it with vs as sorted out the references etc then it worked. Need to sort out styling but at least i can see the new view now. Thanks again

Comment: The article suggested adding the files to the theme project. Did you add the files to the theme or the projection module?

Comment: I could only make it work by adding the classes to the projector module project

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the definition for DisplayLayout() in your CarouselLayou.cs file:

```
    public LocalizedString DisplayLayout(LayoutContext context)
    {
        string columns = context.State.Columns;
        bool horizontal = Convert.ToString(context.State.Alignment) != "vertical";

        return horizontal
                   ? T("{0} columns grid", columns)
                   : T("{0} lines grid", columns);
    }
```

Also, variable 'id' in LayourShapes.cs should be 'Id', and there are other incorrect casings in the  declarations:

```
string outerDivClass = context.state.outerDivClass;
string OuterDivId = context.state.OuterDivID;
string innerDivClass = context.state.InnerDicClass;
string firstItemClass = context.state.FirstItemClass;
string itemClass = context.state.ItemClass;
```

should be:

```
string outerDivClass = context.State.OuterDivClass;
string outerDivId = context.State.OuterDivID;
string innerDivClass = context.State.InnerDicClass;
string firstItemClass = context.State.FirstItemClass;
string itemClass = context.State.ItemClass;
```

Comment: In your casing comments the first one is still lowercase (`outerDivClass`) is that correct?

Comment: It's been a while and I can't remember 100%, but I am pretty sure it is not correct. Have edited, thanks.